# How to keyboard interrupt user32.GetMessageW / user32.SetWinEventHook loop in python?

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, pywin32

I can't seem to figure out how to let Ctrl-C interrupt this code.  It prints a KeyboardInterrupt exception to the console when you press Ctrl-C but never actually stops the program.

How can I make it actually stop?

```py
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
from random import random

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
ole32 = ctypes.windll.ole32

EVENT_MIN = 0x00000001
EVENT_MAX = 0x7FFFFFFF


def _win_callback(
    hWinEventHook: int, event, hwnd, idObject, idChild, idEventThread, dwmsEventTime
):
    if random() > 0.95:
        print(event)


def loop():
    ole32.CoInitializeEx(0)

    win_event_proc_type = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
        None,
        ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,
        ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
        ctypes.wintypes.HWND,
        ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
        ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
        ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
        ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
    )

    win_event_proc = win_event_proc_type(_win_callback)

    winevent_outofcontext = 0x0000
    user32.SetWinEventHook.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
    hook = None

    hook = user32.SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_MIN, EVENT_MAX, 0, win_event_proc, 0, 0, winevent_outofcontext,
    )
    assert hook != 0

    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    print("starting msg loop")
    while user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0) != 0:
        print("msg", msg)
        user32.TranslateMessageW(msg)
        user32.DispatchMessageW(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop()
```

Comment: Have you tried try/except?

Comment: Yes. I even went so far as to wrap the call to `loop` in `try/except` and it won't capture it.  I can add a `try/except` inside the `_win_callback`function and it catches the error, but there's no way to return execution and exit from the `while` loop inside the `loop` function.

Comment: You can create an event via `CreateEventW` and wait on the handle via [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) with `fWaitAll=False`, `dwMilliseconds=-1` (i.e. `INFINITE`), and `dwWakeMask=0x4ff` (i.e. `QS_ALLINPUT`). Reset the event before the loop, and handle `KeyboardInterrupt` in the callback by setting the event. `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` will return 0 (i.e. `WAIT_OBJECT_0`) if the event is set. The return value is 1 if there's a message in the queue, in which case call `GetMessageW`.

Comment: Don't use `windll`. It should really be deprecated. Use `user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)` and `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`. If a function is documented to set the last error when it fails, get the error code and raise an exception via `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`. For ole32.dll, most functions return an `HRESULT` value, so use `ole32 = ctypes.OleDLL('ole32')`, which automatically handles raising an exception for failure codes.